# Two second pause between DVD chapters on .avi split with VirtualDub then produced with DVDFlick

Tags: dvd, avi, virtualdub, dvdauthor

I split an .avi with VirtualDub (file->save segmented file) then turned these files into a DVD using DVD Flick. The result is a two second gap between each chapter. How can I stop this pause so the chapters run together seamlessly (and without the user noticing)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A case of reading the instructions.

The [DVD Flick guide](http://www.dvdflick.net/guide/index_en.html#createdvd) advises:

> **Step 2: Edit your titles**
>
> You can edit each title by double-clicking it or by clicking on it once and pressing the Edit title button. Here you can *set the number of chapters the title will have*, either by entering a number or a time interval.

So, I didn't need to split the .avi file at all. Instead, just drag into DVD Flick, and edit the title (the .avi file) as directed in the guide before creating the DVD.